# how can i proxy :80/abc to :8080 by nginx

Tags: nginx

how can i proxy :80/abc to :8080 by nginx. here is my config and it got 404

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xx.com;
  location /abc/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `proxy_pass` instead of `proxy_redirect`:

```
location /abc/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

I tested that and it worked for me. See [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).